# Recursive Function to change both <x and y> in a matrix?

Tags: python, recursion

ALright I have to write a function that acts like the auto fill function in paint. It has to be recursive; I get principle of recursion and this the first time that I'm using it, here is what i get or something along these lines, then i ask for a set of coordinates that change the "." into "x" accordingly, so far so good except for the function:

....xx....

...x..x...

...x..x...

...x..x...

....xx....

I tried using 5-6 ways and this is the latest:

```
def autoFill(yCoordinate,xCoordinate,listOfCharacters,x,y):

    if listOfCharacters[xCoordinate][yCoordinate]==".":
        flag=True
        listOfCharacters[xCoordinate][yCoordinate]="x"
    else:
        return

    if flag==True:

        if yCoordinate<x and flag2==1:
            autoFill(yCoordinate+1,xCoordinate,listOfCharacters,x,y,yc,xc)
        elif yCoordinate>0:
            autoFill(yCoordinate-1,xCoordinate,listOfCharacters,x,y,yc,xc)
        elif xCoordinate<x:
            autoFill(yCoordinate,xCoordinate+1,listOfCharacters,x,y,yc,xc)
        elif xCoordinate>0:
            autoFill(yCoordinate,xCoordinate-1,listOfCharacters,x,y,yc,xc)

    return listOfCharacters
```

Comment: What's the output should be like? If i set the coordinates to `(0,0)` for example.

Comment: the output would basically change all the "." in a certain area to "x" so to use your example it would change all the dots on the left of the X's to x's also

Comment: So, if the autofill arguments are `start_x, start_y, list, end_x, end_y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
def floodfill (chars, x, y):
        try:
                if chars [y] [x] == 'x': return
                chars [y] [x] = 'x'
                for xoff, yoff in ( (0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0) ):
                        floodfill (chars, x + xoff, y + yoff)
        except: pass
```

For example, this snippet:

```
a = '''....xx....
...x..x...
...x..x...
...x..x...
....xx....'''

chars = [ [c for c in line] for line in a.split ('\n') ]
floodfill (chars, 0, 0)
print ('\n'.join (''.join (c for c in line) for line in chars) )

print ('-' * 20)

chars = [ [c for c in line] for line in a.split ('\n') ]
floodfill (chars, 5, 3)
print ('\n'.join (''.join (c for c in line) for line in chars) )
```

Produces the output:

```
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxx..xxxx
xxxx..xxxx
xxxx..xxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
--------------------
....xx....
...xxxx...
...xxxx...
...xxxx...
....xx....
```

Without the loop:

```
def floodfill (chars, x, y):
        try:
                if chars [y] [x] == 'x': return
                chars [y] [x] = 'x'
                floodfill (chars, x + 1, y)
                floodfill (chars, x - 1, y)
                floodfill (chars, x, y + 1)
                floodfill (chars, x, y - 1)
        except: pass
```

Comment: can't use loops, has to be a strictly recursive function

Comment: @boolean See the last paragraph. I added code without a single loop.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues.

First and foremost, you're referencing a couple non-existent variables, `yc` and `xc` in the recursive calls. They don't appear to be needed, perhaps they're held over from a previous version of the code. Just get rid of them.

The next issue is the use of `flag2` in the `if` test towards the end, which is also undefined. Drop it too.

There's a second issue in that `if`, that you're testing `yCoordinate` against the `x` width, rather than against `y` (and really `x` and `y` are poor names, consider changing them to something like `width` and `height`).

With that you'll almost be there. The other issue (and the main logic bug) is that you're using `elif`s in your final block, rather than letting each `if` be tested independently. You want to be able to recurse up to four times from a given square, only skipping directions that go out of bounds. So make the `elif`s into regular `if`s.

Oh, and you might want to be using `>=` for your tests against `0`, since that's probably a valid coordinate!

One last thing that's not a bug, but can still be improved. Your current code using the `flag` variable is unnecessarily complicated. You can simplify it by changing your first `if` statement to test the reverse (that the coordinates specified are not `"."`, or perhaps instead that they are `"x"`). If the test is true, you can do the `return` you currently have in your `else` block. After that, you can run all the rest of the code (starting with setting a list value to `"x"`, then recursing) unconditionally. This is a very common structure for recursive code:

```
def recursive_func(x):
    if base_case(x):
        return

    recursive_func(something(x))
```